# How to sum and group by sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum

```
SELECT tr.id_kasir, 
       tr.tgl_transaksi, 
       CASE tr.id_member 
         WHEN 'M000' THEN Sum (mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) + Sum( 
                          mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) * 0.1 
                          - Nvl2 (pro.discount, Sum(mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) 
                                                * 
                                                ( pro.discount / 100 ), 0 
                            ) 
         ELSE Sum(mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) - 
              Sum(mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) * 
              0.05 + Sum 
                     (mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) * 0.1 - 
              Nvl2 (pro.discount, Sum(mn.harga_menu * st.qty_menu) * ( 
                                  pro.discount / 100 ), 0 
              ) 
       END Setoran 
FROM   transaksi tr 
       JOIN struk st 
         ON ( st.no_transaksi = tr.no_transaksi ) 
       JOIN menu mn 
         ON ( st.kode_menu = mn.kode_menu ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN promo pro 
                    ON ( pro.kode_menu = mn.kode_menu ) 
GROUP  BY tr.id_kasir, 
          tr.tgl_transaksi, 
          tr.id_member, 
          pro.discount 
ORDER  BY tr.tgl_transaksi, 
          tr.id_kasir
```

This query is working and the output like this :

```
ID_KASIR    TGL_TRANSAKSI   SETORAN
  C001       23-OCT-14       38000
  C002       23-OCT-14       30800
  C001       24-OCT-14       168000 
  C002       24-OCT-14       16500
  C002       25-OCT-14       27500
  C002       25-OCT-14       26250
```

But I want to sum setoran, group by `id_kasir` and `tgl_transaksi`
can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have your query in `cte` and do the group by using this result.

```
with cte 
as
( 

your current query

)
select ID_KASIR , TGL_TRANSAKSI, SUM(SETORAN) as total
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID_KASIR, TGL_TRANSAKSI
```